# Megaboard Problems about pySerial Communication from Python to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I asked same question on another forum, but i need more opinions and advices.

I wrote a simple Python code and Arduino code.

In my code, the Excel matrix data is loaded into Python,
then converted into a numpy form of matrix data in Python,
and then extracted the values of each element of the matrix converted into numpy.
Each extracted element value is a screw lead value.
These screw lead values are calculated and converted to the number of revolutions of each screw.

These converted screw rotational speed values are now transferred to Arduino using pySerial.
Once the values of the screw revolutions are transmitted to Arduino,
rotate the step motor connected to Arduino by the number of revolutions of the screw.

So here's my Python code.:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import serial
import time

py_serial = serial.Serial( 
    port="COM5",
    baudrate=9600
) 

Location = 'C:/Users/KIMWONKI' 
File = 'excel_example.xlsx' 

data_pd = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/KIMWONKI/excel_example.xlsx',
                        header=None, index_col=None, names=None) 

data_np = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(data_pd) 

start = 2
pitch = 3
lead = 0 

for i, row in enumerate(data_np):
    for j, element in enumerate(row): 
        lead = data_np[i][j] 
        rotation = lead/(start*pitch) 
        reverse_rotation = - rotation 
        rotation = round(rotation, 6) 
        if rotation > 0: 
            print(f'motor rotates in the forward direction at {abs(rotation)} times.') 
            rotation = str(rotation) 
            py_serial.write(rotation.encode()) 
            time.sleep(8)
```

And next is my Arduino code.:

```
int DIRM=8; 
int PULM=9; 
int DIRP=10;
int PULP=11;
float rot_number = 0; 
float sig; 

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode (DIRM, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (PULM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (DIRP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PULP, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    sig = Serial.parseFloat(); // sig is rotation number inputted from python
    if(sig > 0){ 
      rot_number = sig; // rotation number
      rotate_CW(rot_number); 
      delay(1000); 
      rot_number = 0; 
      break;
    }
    else if(sig < 0){ 
      rot_number = sig;
      rot_number = abs(rot_number); 
      rotate_CCW(rot_number); 
      delay(1000);
      rot_number=0; 
      break;   
    }
    else{
      break;
    }
  }
}

void rotate_CW(float rotation_number) 
{
  int numberOfRounds = int (rotation_number * 4000); 

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++){ 
    digitalWrite(DIRM,LOW);
    digitalWrite(DIRP,HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(PULP,HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(PULM,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    digitalWrite(PULP,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100);
  }
}

void rotate_CCW(float rotation_number) // reverse rotation function
{
  int numberOfRounds = int (rotation_number * 4000); 

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++){ 
    digitalWrite(DIRM,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(DIRP,LOW);  
    digitalWrite(PULP,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(PULM,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    digitalWrite(PULP,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100);
  }
}
```

I connected four input/output cables attached to the step motor driver to Arduino. I wrote the code accordingly. DIRM stands for DIR-pin and DIRP stands for DIR+pin PULM means PUL-pin and PULP means PUL+ pin.

I first connected the Arduino Uno board, ran the Arduino code, and then ran the Python code.

Here is the terminal output appears in the Python program.:

```
motor rotates in the forward direction at 0.5 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 1.166667 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 1.333333 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 1.5 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 0.833333 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 0.666667 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 1.333333 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 1.333333 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 0.666667 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 0.333333 times.
motor rotates in the forward direction at 1.666667 times.
```

When using the Arduino Uno board, the motor actually 'rotated' to match the output of this terminal, with 0.5 turns, 1.166667 turns, 1.333333 turns, etc.

But now **I changed the board from Arduino Unoboard to Mega Board, and the motor didn't work.**

It's not like there was an error message in particular, or the code didn't execute at all. Only the output message came from the above terminal output window, and the motor did not rotate.

I checked where the problem occurred. Through the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE, I directly entered the screw revolution value into the Arduino code and found that the motor rotated normally regardless of whether it was using the Arduino Uno board or the Arduino Mega board.

However, the attempt to run Python and transfer the screw revolution value data to Excel->Python->Arduino was only possible on the Arduino Uno board. When the Arduino Mega Board was used, the Python terminal output window still says 'N times' but the motor did not actually rotate.

I checked all the board rates and port names. Board rate settings and port settings were correct, but still motor does not rotate. I don't know where the problem is.

The megaboard I used is 2560 megaboard. My code is a mess, but I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: write a simple arduino sketch that runs the motor for one second, stops for one second, reverses motor for one second, stops for one second and repeats

Comment: Insert `time.sleep(2)` following  `py_serial = serial.Serial(...`. It may or may not have anything to do with your actual problem, but it is something you should do anyway, if nothing else to eliminate it as a question as to whether not it matters.